# How to filter URLs in Nutch 2.1 solrindex command

Tags: java, solr, nutch

How do I prevent some pages I fetched from getting indexed when I run a `bin/nutch solrindex` command? I would like to define and use a regex-urlfilter.txt like I did at fetch time.

I'm using Nutch 2.1 and according to http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch%20solrindex the option just disappeared. I checked the source code and can't find any clue about the matter.

Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that an index filter plugin should be used.

I followed [Hartl's tutorial](http://florianhartl.com/nutch-plugin-tutorial.html) to organize and link the source code.

Here is the interesting part of the code:

```
public NutchDocument filter(NutchDocument doc, String url, WebPage page)
    throws IndexingException {
    String input_url = url;
    try {
        url = urlNormalizers.normalize(url, URLNormalizers.SCOPE_DEFAULT);
        url = urlFilters.filter(url); // filter the url
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.warn("Skipping " + input_url + ":" + e);
        return null;
    }  
    if (url == null) {
        LOG.info("Skipping (filter): " + input_url);
        return null;
    }  
    return doc;
}

public void setConf(Configuration conf) {
    this.conf = conf;
    this.urlFilters = new URLFilters(conf);
    urlNormalizers = new URLNormalizers(conf, URLNormalizers.SCOPE_INJECT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your exclusion criteria?

Can you exclude them at the fetch/parse stages?

Comment: I'm crawling websites having two types of pages: "records list" (links) and "records". I need to fetch the first one to retrieve the links leading to the records. But I'm only interested in indexing "record" pages.

Comment: Do you have access to the pages? If so, you could add a metatag content="noindex,follow" and Nutch will respect that, extracting the outlinks but not crawling the content.

Comment: If you don't then you could filter the results out at the query stage in SOLR

Comment: I don't have access and I'm crawling a non-limited number of chosen websites so it seems a bit heavy to do this at query stage :/
I'm studying two options for now: index filters (I would have to write a nutch plugin)  or rewriting my own hadoop/hbase indexing job...

Comment: Looks like writing a custom Nutch plugin is the way forward. You could start from lib-regex-urlfilter, it should be a good starting point.